# Convert mapbox Add a polygon to a map using a GeoJSON source to react

Tags: html, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I have the following Mapbox code and it works in an HTML file, It displays a polygon of a set of coordinates using the Mapbox. I am having problems converting it to react code and have it work in the same way.

You can copy the code and place it in an HTML file and see the output. I just need a react component snippet code that displaysys same out put. Thanks alot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add a polygon to a map using a GeoJSON source</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZW1tYW51ZWxud2Fub2NoaWUiLCJhIjoiY2t0bGozd2YwMDJpcjJ1czh2aHVscmk1eCJ9.XlprBONdRkZdwS4NYdKbGw';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container ID
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10', // style URL
        center: [-68.137343, 45.137451], // starting position
        zoom: 5 // starting zoom
    });

    map.on('load', () => {
        // Add a data source containing GeoJSON data.
        map.addSource('maine', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Polygon',
                    // These coordinates outline Maine.
                    'coordinates': [
                        [
                            [-67.13734, 45.13745],
                            [-66.96466, 44.8097],
                            [-68.03252, 44.3252],
                            [-69.06, 43.98],
                            [-70.11617, 43.68405],
                            [-70.64573, 43.09008],
                            [-70.75102, 43.08003],
                            [-70.79761, 43.21973],
                            [-70.98176, 43.36789],
                            [-70.94416, 43.46633],
                            [-71.08482, 45.30524],
                            [-70.66002, 45.46022],
                            [-70.30495, 45.91479],
                            [-70.00014, 46.69317],
                            [-69.23708, 47.44777],
                            [-68.90478, 47.18479],
                            [-68.2343, 47.35462],
                            [-67.79035, 47.06624],
                            [-67.79141, 45.70258],
                            [-67.13734, 45.13745]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        });

        // Add a new layer to visualize the polygon.
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'maine',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'maine', // reference the data source
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': '#0080ff', // blue color fill
                'fill-opacity': 0.5
            }
        });
        // Add a black outline around the polygon.
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'outline',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'maine',
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'line-color': '#000',
                'line-width': 3
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. used the react-mapbox-gl package for it

```
import MapGL, { Source, Layer } from "@urbica/react-map-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

export default function App() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 45.137451890638886,
    longitude: -68.13734351262877,
    zoom: 5,
  });

  const data = {
    type: "Feature",
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
          [-67.13734, 45.13745],
          [-66.96466, 44.8097],
          [-68.03252, 44.3252],
          [-69.06, 43.98],
          [-70.11617, 43.68405],
          [-70.64573, 43.09008],
          [-70.75102, 43.08003],
          [-70.79761, 43.21973],
          [-70.98176, 43.36789],
          [-70.94416, 43.46633],
          [-71.08482, 45.30524],
          [-70.66002, 45.46022],
          [-70.30495, 45.91479],
          [-70.00014, 46.69317],
          [-69.23708, 47.44777],
          [-68.90478, 47.18479],
          [-68.2343, 47.35462],
          [-67.79035, 47.06624],
          [-67.79141, 45.70258],
          [-67.13734, 45.13745],
        ],
      ],
    },
  };

  return (
    <MapGL
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9"
      accessToken={
        "pk.eyJ1IjoiZW1tYW51ZWxud2Fub2NoaWUiLCJhIjoiY2t0bGozd2YwMDJpcjJ1czh2aHVscmk1eCJ9.XlprBONdRkZdwS4NYdKbGw"
      }
      onViewportChange={setViewport}
      {...viewport}
    >
      <Source id="maine" type="geojson" data={data} />
      <Layer
        id="maine"
        type="fill"
        source="maine"
        paint={{
          "fill-color": "red",
          "fill-opacity": 0.8,
        }}
      />
    </MapGL>
  );
}
```